# Question about divisibility and and division algorithm.

Tags: divisibility

I have a question about divisibility and and division algorithm:

if C = Ax + By, D|C and D|B then D|A?
I thought yes, because C is a combination of A and B, and if D divides B and C, then it must divide A.
This is true?  If so, how can I justify (mathematically)
Thanks.

Comment: More context is needed: to debug your reasoning we need to know *precisely* how you deduce $\,D\mid A.\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

Since $D$ divides $A,C$, we can write $A=mD$ and $C=nD$ for some $m,n$. But then
$$
\begin{split}
C&= Ax + By \\
nD&= mD + By \\
(n-m)D&= By
\end{split}
$$
But then notice that this just implies $D$ divides $By$, not necessarily $B$ or $y$. This suggests there is a counterexample. See if you can come up with one! [Maybe start 'backwards' by choosing $D$ to be a prime that divides $C$ and $B$ but perhaps not $A$.]